# Is it ok that 2 objects reference each other?

Tags: c#, class, oop

I'm making a chess game in C#. I've got 2 classes, Field and Piece:

```
public class Field
{
    // the piece that is standing on this field
    // null if no piece is standing on it
    public Piece piece { get; set; }
}

public class Piece
{
    // the field this piece is standing on
    public Field field { get; set; }
}
```

When a piece moves, this method is called (in class Piece):

```
public void Move(Field field)
{
    this.field = field;
    field.piece = this;
}
```

This doesn't seem to be good coding, because everytime I change the field property, I also have to change the piece property for that field. I do need both properties though, because elsewhere in my code, I need them both to do checks etc (e.g. what's the field this piece is on and by what piece is this field taken).

My question: is this completely ok, is it a bad code smell or is it totally wrong? What would be a good solution to solve this?

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on how you use it. In some cases you might want to use events instead or use certain parts of your logic somewhere else. But to answer you question if it's totally wrong: No - there are plenty of applications where you would reference a parent object, even in the .Net Framework there are a lot of cases. You might want to add a specific example to your code (More details or code).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added some more code and a clearer explanation. I think events is what I might use, so everytime a piece is moved, its field changes as well, or something.

Comment: No problem, imo.

Comment: Sure it's allowed, but you have to pay more attention, that you always keep it in sync. Else you might get some strange effects. A piece that points to a field, but the field contains another piece. It's a good practice to maintain these constraints (assignments of fields/pieces) by internal methods, so in a separated assembly that will ensure it's always in sync. So putting the chess board/pieces/fields in a separate assembly, would be a good practice.

Comment: Children know their parents and parents know their kids. So, yes, mutual references between objects certainly applies to real world scenarios. Use accordingly.

Comment: It is an optimization, one less reference to have to defer.  The odds it pays off in a chess game is really, really low.  Both the chess playing logic and the chess-board painting code is much, much more expensive.  If you don't have that kind of insight, common, then always favor a profiler.  Takes about a year of repeatedly using it to get the big picture.  Then you dig in what a reference really does and you get to be a programmer that gets a nice big pay-raise.

Comment: You are modelling chess. You have 64 spaces only. Searching that even using brute force is trivial. Just have the one reference and compute the other as needed. A piece should not have a reference to a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see here is that you have `Piece.field` and `Field.piece` as public properties. This means that others can set these properties without updating the corresponding one.

Additionally, when you move a piece from one field to another, you don't remove the piece from the previous field, and we allow pieces to move to occupied squares, which will result in multiple pieces referring to the same field, but the field will only refer to the last piece placed there.

To address these, I would make the properties read only (with a private setter), forcing clients to call the corresponding `Set` or `Move` method to change them. Then, in this method, we can verify that the field we're moving to is not occupied (if it is, we simply throw an exception - the client must check this first before calling `Move`), and that we clear the `Piece` from the `Field` we moved from.

The validation work can be done in either the `Field` or `Piece` class, or both. I put it all in the `Field` class to simplify things.

Even still, there are problems with this. You can call `Field.SetPiece(piece)` directly (instead of `Piece.MoveTo(field);`), which will leave the piece with a `null` value for `Field`. So this is only a slight improvement, but not the ideal solution. See below for a better idea.

```
public class Field
{
    public Piece Piece { get; private set; }
    public bool Occupied => Piece != null;

    public void ClearPiece()
    {
        // Remove this field from the piece
        if (Piece?.Field == this) Piece.MoveTo(null);

        // Remove the piece from this field
        Piece = null;
    }

    public void SetPiece(Piece piece)
    {
        if (piece != null)
        {
            if (Occupied)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    $"Field is already occupied by {Piece}.");
            }

            // Remove piece from the piece's previous field
            if (piece.Field?.Piece == piece)
            {
                piece.Field.ClearPiece();
            }
        }

        Piece = piece;
    }
}

public class Piece
{
    public Field Field { get; private set; }

    public void MoveTo(Field field)
    {
        field.SetPiece(this);
        Field = field;
    }
}
```

---

After thinking a little more about this, I think a better solution would be to have a `GameManager` class that handles all the validation and movement, and then we can make the `Field` and `Piece` classes "dumb".

This makes sense because there is a lot more validation to be done before setting a `Piece` on a `Field`. Is it ok to move this piece to the location (i.e. if the King is in check and this doesn't block it, then it's not allowed). Is the `Field` a valid landing spot for the piece based on the piece's move rules (i.e. a horizontal position for a bishop would not be allowed)? Is there anything blocking the path of the piece to get to the destination? Is the destination occupied by another piece belonging to the same player? Many things to evaluate before moving a piece.

Additionally, this would allow us to reuse the `Piece` and `Field` classes in other types of games, which may have a different set of rules, and a different `GameManager` to enforce them.

Answer (score 0):

**No!** This relates to concept of *circular dependency*. Although applied for modules, this may very well be seen as precursor for such.

More concretely, this is an ideal example for *mutually recursive* objects. Conceptually, if you substitute (semi-pseudocode)

```
public class Field
{
    public Piece piece {
        public Field field {
            public Piece piece {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's because the objects are defined in terms of each other. Then theoretically you can 
do something like

```
this.field.piece.field.piece...
```